# How do i remove the selection drawing from a Qt QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: windows, qt, selection, qgraphicsscene

I am developing a Qt 4.8 application using QGraphicsScene on Windows XP. 
When the user double clicks on a QGraphicsTextItem, i call

```
textItem->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
```

At the next selection change i call

```
textItem->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
```

This works correctly, but i find no way to remove the inversion of the background color that remains from editing. In the screen shot below, i first double clicked on the first text item and selected the characters "2927". Then i clicked on the second test item and selected "est". I find no way to get rid of the still inverted "2927" in the first text item (although its not in edit mode anymore).

[image]

I also tried to call:

```
    textItem->textCursor().clearSelection();
    textItem->update();
    textItem->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
    textItem->clearFocus();
```

But his does not at all change the behavior.

So now i found a workaround:

```
    QString s = textItem->toPlainText();
    textItem->setPlainText("");
    textItem->setPlainText(s);
    textItem->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
```

I dont like that, but it works.

Any hint for a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `QGraphicsTextItem::textCursor()` returns a copy of the cursor, you have to set it back to the text item for it to have any effect.

```
QTextCursor cursor(textItem->textCursor());
cursor.clearSelection();
textItem->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that! Strange that it doesn't work. I was going to suggest making sure that the call to `clearSelection()` is actually being executed but if your workaround is working I guess it's likely the other code was being called correctly. Perhaps I'll try an experiment on this end.